# How to enable kdelicious in konqueror?

Tags: 10.10, kde, extension, delicious

I have the package kdelicious installed (Maverick), and would expect to use its extensions in Konqueror. How do I enable it?

Answer (score 1):

kdelicious: delicious for konqueror

At last I managed to find a plugin for delicious in konqueror. The project is Called kdelicious (although There Are Several Projects That Are The Same Nearly extinct or name). The point is That There is no package to install so Then I Have Explained how to 
compile and configure it.

**Downloading and Compiling the sources**

We have installed the packages: kdelibs5-dev make cmake git-core

```
git clone
git://github.com/greghaynes/kdelicious.git
cd kdelicious/ 
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr make
```

**Installation**

We have two options:

Using the Makefile target:

make [ install | uninstall ]

Create a debian package:

sudo checkinstall -D make install

dpkg [ -i | -r ] kdelicious_XXXXXXXX.deb

**Configuring Konqueror**

*Activate the plugin:*

settings > configure extensions

*Activate the toolbar "extra" to see the icon*

settings > toolbar  > extra toolbar

*Show only the icon (no text)*

right click on the icon > text possition > icons only

If we do not like the default icon that brings you can download the logo of delicious:

```
wget http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_ABRRWS9Ucgw/SlZlZ5I614I/AAAAAAAAAKQ/_jFllqGkpXM/ s400/delicious_logo.png
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/share/icons
sudo mv delicious_logo.png /usr/local/share/icons
```

and to change the icon:

settings > configure toolbars
    Extra Toolbar 
    change icon > other icons > browse

Done. We Can Comfortably saved links on delicious from konqueror INSTEAD OF HAVING to use the http:/delicious.com/save.